# Advanced sorting of content in wordpress

Tags: sort, content

Let's just say that I have website about cars. I have already created several categories, depending on which brand the cars are. My question is simple. I would like to implement some advanced type of sort for users. Let's say, that I have already above 50 cars in my Porsche category, and I would like to give user opportunity, where he can decide to display only yellow porsches, or only porsches, which are more than 20 years old, and so on. 
I just started with wordpress and I have not found anything about this topic in hours of googling.
I have basic skills of mysql, advanced in html, ccs
I would rather find some existing plugin for this, than creating all the stuff on my own
There is a typical thing, which I would like to achive on my website - http://wotreplays.com/ - you can see, how you can sort replays of the games by nations, tiers, type of vehicles, and so on.
Anyway, thank anyone for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you want to do you can get just with ordinary custom fields. I can imagine custom fields like colour, age, brand etc. and theirs filtering according to user's selection in frontend.

Please read about custom fields here

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

There are some awesome plugins for creating custom fields too. One of my favourite is Advanced custom fields

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is exactly what I was talking about, but I did not know the name of the topic, and even though I've seen/read some tutorials, this was not covered,

Comment: Only link-based answers are not good.